# Two Eclispse projects -> One Eclipse Plug-in

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pdt

### Background

I'm a developer of the [Vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net) project.

Vrapper contains of 2 major parts

- Vim-emulation library (vrapper.core)
- Eclipse part that makes a good use of it

We want vrapper.core to be Eclipse-unaware, so it's reusable
outside of the Eclipse. Currently, we can "vrap" all sorts of Eclipse
text editors and our little mock text editor that we use for unit testing.

vrapper.core implements all sorts of Vim commands, modes, etc.
Those all communicate with Platform - an interface that abstracts out
underlying stuff (text editor, clipboards, settings system, etc.).

When mode is created for an editor it asks platform if there are extra
commands that are approperiate for underlying editor, currently edited file type, etc.

EclipsePlatform provides those commands using Eclipse extension points mechanism.

So, let's consider the following projects (there are more):

- *vrapper.core* - Eclipse-independent code for Vrapper
- *vrapper.eclipse* - Eclipse plug-in that depends on *vrapper.core*
- *surround.core* - Eclipse-independent code that emulates *surround.vim* (Vim plug-in)
- *surround.eclipse* - Eclipse fragment for *vrapper.eclipse*
  that makes it provide commands form *surround.core*.

There are two ways we can deal with those:

#### One plug-in to rule them all

This is how it should look like from Eclipse's perspective.
There is one plug-in that contains code from *vrapper.eclipse* and *vrapper.core*,
and one fragment that contains code from *surround.core* and *surround.eclipse*.

#### Many plug-ins

- There are 3 plug-ins

  - two OSGified libraries *vrapper.core*, *surround.core*
  - *vrapper.eclipse*
- *surround.eclipse* fragment depends on *vrapper.core* in this case

### Problems

Many plug-ins solution have some issues with lazy class loading that I don't understand.
It's beacause when instances of modes from *vrapper.core* are created they need
classes from *surround.core* to be created (via *vrapper.eclipse* -> *surround.eclipse*).

This works if you run stuff from Eclipse and select all plug-ins from run configuration,
but if one deploys features & plugins and run eclipse normally an exception is thrown
because classes from surround.core cannot be found.
It's something in the spirit of *surround.core asking for extra commands from
dependent plug-ins creates **implicit circular dependencies***.

What I mean by *implicit* dependencies is that no core class depends on eclipse-specific classes in compile time.

Modes (like vim normal mode) are core classes. They contain commands. There are some commands specific for particular Eclipse editors (like run this JDT-specific refactoring). Those commands implement core interfaces, but their code (obviously) lives in eclipse-specific projects. When mode is created it asks underlying platform for some extra commands - those extra commands are implemented in eclipse plug-ins. This is when lazy class loading in eclipse make everything blow up in runtime - classes for extra commands are referenced by extension points, but they are not yet loaded. Boom, exception.

I tried to work this around by using "one plug-in to rule them all" approach.
Having just one plug-in seems to be much better solution to me, but I couldn't make it work cleanly.

Only thing that succeeded for me was quite an ugly hack.

- All *.core* projects had an Ant task that created .jar file with their classes
  and dropped it into corresponding **.eclipse* project
- **.eclipse* projects included that jars and had them enlisted in MANIFEST files.

The problem with this ugly hack approach (besides of it being ugly hack) is
that development becomes quite painful.  Eclipse code navigation, code coverage
and few other things in Eclipse stops working.

### Summary

We have *eclipse independent library + eclipse specific stuff* architecture,
but we really need all of this to live in one plug-in (because there are some dependencies in both directions).

How do I make code from few projects live into one plug-in/fragment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out that adding [Eclipse-BuddyPolicy: dependent](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Context_Class_Loader_Enhancements#Buddy_Policy) to MANIFEST.MF files, reexporting some dependencies and turning one fragment into plugin (so there is plug-in dependency for BuddyPolicy to track) was the right solution.

Problem solved :-)

Answer (score 0):

From reading this it sounds as if the actual problem is the fact that there are dependencies in both directions. Can't you refactor your projects to make only the Eclipse-spcific proejcts depend on the core projects, and not the other way around?

Comment: This is a good point, but unfortunately no. I have just edited my question and explained what I mean by dependencies in both directions better